# Unity - Colliding canvas elements with viewport elements using WorldToScreenPoint per vertex

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wish to make collide a UI element with a viewport element. To achieve this I figured I take the collision data `EdgeCollider2D` of the viewport element and convert each of its vertices to Screen space, then assign the points to another canvas element which has an `EdgeCollider2D` on it.

Problem is, the generated collision is way off, and I can't figure out why is that.

Here's my short code:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(EdgeCollider2D))]
public class ScreenSpaceEdgeCollisionGenerator : MonoBehaviour, IScreenSpaceCollisionGenerator {

    public EdgeCollider2D target;

    private void Update() {
        GenerateCollision();
    }

    public void GenerateCollision() {
        var mEdge = GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
        var viewportPts = target.points;
        Vector2[] n_Pts = new Vector2[viewportPts.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < viewportPts.Length; i++) {
            n_Pts[i] = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(viewportPts[i]);
        }

        mEdge.points = n_Pts;
    }
}
```

here's the result:

[image: img1]

On this first image you see how off the collision data is.

[image: img2]

On this second image the red rect is the viewport element, while the white square is the ui element. I use only one, the main camera, the same which is used to determine the point transformation. The viewport element's `EdgeCollider2D` is placed on top of the red rect, as it should be.